# Why is an obvious NAA not deleted?

Tags: support, review, late-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139588/203657) obviously is not-an-answer to the extent of being a good audit candidate. Flagged as such; the flag was marked helpful but the post not deleted.

Why not? Is there any change in policy I missed?

Comment: it looks like a review queue failure. Reflagged.

Comment: Thats pretty much a textbook not an answer, I'm adding my flag to yours

Comment: Added my flag too.

Comment: Going to guess it was a mistake, it is obviously not an answer.

Comment: ...which answer? :)

Comment: The flag was dismissed because the answer was deleted, but the guy just undeleted it again, so yeah. It's gone now anyway.

Comment: When did you flag that answer?

Comment: @hims056 some time yesterday (can't see a more precise time right now)

Comment: Curious: There is no revision history for it's previous deletion but it has history of undeletion in it's [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19139588/revisions "10K only")

Comment: @hims056: If the post was deleted by review, then that might have been the cause. Apparently review-deletions do not create a revision entry.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - Ohh. I thought it might show `deleted by Community ♦`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the post *was* deleted as a result of 6 "Recommend Deletion" reviews, which dismisses all flags on it and for some reason does not show up in the revision history.

However, if a post gets deleted in such a manner, there is nothing stopping you from simply undeleting it again, which is what that guy did. Since it was no longer in the review queue and had no active flags on it, it must've slipped off the radar after that.

Comment: thanks for the info, being able to simply undelete sounds like a bug to me

Comment: @kleopatra Probably is. I don't think you can do that if you get any actual delete votes from 20k+ people or mods though.

Comment: might be safe in that case: currently the answer has a single undelete vote on it - which could well be the poster's own (as nobody else would ..)

Comment: @kleopatra we can to put our two undeletes, then we will see, whos, where, how and for why....

Comment: @mKorbel I don't want it undeleted :-)